# C++ in bash shell script, super beginner questions about calling functions and debugging

Tags: c++, bash, unix, gdb

My assignment is to debug a program written out by the professor. We have to do all of it in putty, and I'm new at bash shell scripting (read: I know basically nothing about functions and handling C++ programs).

So I compile the untitled.cpp file and it makes the program untitled. Then I execute the program with ./untitled which makes it run. Good so far. The program displays "Seed Value? " and I enter the given value as per the assignment. Then, since the program is over, the command prompt goes back to the directory of untitled. I'm not sure what to do next, because that's what all my questions are about.

Here's the instruction:

> Run the program (single step) and enter a seed value of 3222011. After
>   calling the shuffle() function, what is the value of array[8]?

**Disclaimer: I'm not asking for answers, only how to find them.** There's 7 more questions after the one I just mentioned.

My questions:

1. How do I find the array element value? Or the value of any data member, really?
2. Later on it says " You can print the contents of the entire array in the main() function by typing the gdb command print array." This does not work. It only returns "no symbol "array" in current context.
3. What does it mean to "step" into a function and how do I do it?

The given program is:

---

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::flush;

const int ARRAYSIZE = 30;

void fill(int ar[], int size);
void shuffle(int ar[], int size);

int main(void)
{

  int array[ARRAYSIZE] = {0}; // Clear out array
  int seed;

  cout << "Seed value? " << flush;
  cin >> seed;
  srand(seed);

  fill(array, ARRAYSIZE);

  shuffle(array, ARRAYSIZE);

  return 0;
}

void fill(int b[], int size)
{
  int index;

  // Place random values at random locations in the array
  for(int i = 0; i < 10 * size; i++)
    {
      index = rand() % size;
      b[index] = rand();
    }
}

void shuffle(int ar [], int size)
{
  int* first, * second;

  for(int j = 0; j < 5 * size; j++)
    {
      // Pick a random pair of positions to swap
      first  = ar + rand() % size;
      second = ar + rand() % size;

      // Swap
      int temp = *first;
      *first = *second;
      *second = temp;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: _'Disclaimer: I'm not asking for answers, only how to find them'_ So that seriously disables your question to be appropriate for SO!

Comment: Asking for search options and triaging answers found aren't apprpriate primary questions on SO!

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with shell scripts.

Comment: Man, my teacher makes up his own terminology for things and sometimes doesn't give us proper (or beginner friendly) names for things. I don't know the exact terminology but I know bash is a shell, and the bash shell keeps telling me I'm entering the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am almost giving you answer here. But you should learn how to use gdb.

Your teacher is testing these things
-- whether you know how to run gdb or not
-- whether you know how to attach a break point
-- whether you know how to print a value while you are debugging a program using gdb

You compile your program with --ggdb option e.g

g++ -ggdb untitled.cpp

Then this is how you attach gdb to your program

gdb a.out

Once you do that you will be in gdb command prompt. Your program has not started yet. Before you start the program, you need to create a "breakpoint" like this

b 27

This created breakpoint at line 27 of untitled.cpp

Then type r to run the program

r

Enter your seed value and press Enter. You will see that gdb brought you at your breakpoint i.e line 27 of your program. Now you can print the value you wanted to see.

Here are the steps

```
snegi@snegi-p7-1267c:~/Workspace/scripts$ gdb a.out 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>...
Reading symbols from /home/satyarth/Workspace/scripts/a.out...done.
(gdb) b 27
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40094c: file untitled.cpp, line 27.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/satyarth/Workspace/scripts/a.out 
Seed value? 3222011

Breakpoint 1, main () at untitled.cpp:27
27    return 0;
(gdb) p array[8]
$1 = 560529867
```

Comment: I know the teacher is trying to test me, it's just that I can't find the resources I need. I know how to compile the program just fine, but I can't find a centralized list of commands for gdb. And since the program was returning nothing, and gdb didn't recognize my commands, I had no idea what to put where.

Also, I tried 'info gdb' and it sent me to the info page for gdbm, and that's wildly different from gdb. I tried 'man gdb' and none of it was relevant to the topic.

Thanks for the last bit though, just giving me an example of syntax works. (there's also 7 more questions I didn't mention)

Comment: So what you're saying is that I find the value of the array element by putting the breakpoint after the shuffle function is called, then displaying the array element at that point. But where did the "p" come from? What's the point of the $1?

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow typically is a one question per post forum, however you've put in good effort in framing the question hence would like to point you in the right direction.

> Do I do these on the same line as the program or do I do them after
>   executing the file? Basically, where and how do I call the shuffle
>   function?

`After calling the shuffle() function, what is the value of array[8]?`

You don't have to call the shuffle function. Its already called in the main program. The instructor is asking you to evaluate value of the array after its called in main.

---

Here is a GDB tutorial for beginners that should answer the rest of your questions. 
[Beej's Quick Guide to GDB](http://beej.us/guide/bggdb/)

Comment: This should be a comment!

Comment: I do agree with you @g-makulik. It too much info for a comment. If you insist nevertheless, I'll move this post.

Comment: The one asking the question here (he doesn't want new answers, but links to existing (reliable?) ones) ...

Comment: 1. it is my fault, I'm just really tired of going back through my lecture notes and the professor's links and finding nothing helpful. Bad questions on the internet are my desperation move.

2. I did have that link bookmarked, but what I need is a complete list of commands to use in gdb, all in one centralized table.